# make this matlab snippet run without a loop

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I want a code the below code more efficient timewise. preferably without a loop.

arguments:

```
t % time values vector
t_index = c % one of the possible indices ranging from 1:length(t).
A % a MXN array where M = length(t)
B % a 1XN array
```

code:

```
m = 1;
for k = t_index:length(t)
        A(k,1:(end-m+1)) = A(k,1:(end-m+1)) + B(m:end); 
        m = m + 1;
end
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd built from B a matrix of size NxM (call it B2), with zeros in the right places and a triangular from according to the conditions and then all you need to do is `A+B2`.

something like this:

```
N=size(A,2);
B2=zeros(size(A));
k=c:length(t);
B2(k(1):k(N),:)=hankel(B)
ans=A+B2;
```

Note, the fact that it is "vectorized" doesn't mean it is faster these days. Matlab's JIT makes for loops comparable and sometimes faster than built-in vectorized options.

Comment: I had a similar solution but I deleted it, I couldn't get it quite right :) Not to mention that I got out-of-memory errors from the `hankel` function with the sizes the OP was using

Comment: I'm not sure this is better than the for loop in performance at all. Why would the `hankel` get you out of memory?

Comment: actually a for loop does a better job on my computer... Many thanks anyways, i've still learned quite alot from the experience.